# Targeting US market, is there anything specific that should be included?

Tags: seo, copy

We've been tasked with building a website and the customer wants to specifically target the US market (North America).

In terms of build, SEO and wording, is there anything specific that should be included to target the US market?

If it makes any difference the site will be built on Wordpress.

We're UK based and tend to build websites that are either targeting locally or at most the UK. I know certain keyword terms such as US locations would need to be included but is there anything else?

I'm trying to think out of the box with this such as US spelling e.g UK - realise, US - realize.

**UPDATE:**

The general consensus within the office is that wording and language plays a big part. American's tend to shorten phrases and get to the point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Google Webmaster Tools under `Site Configuration` > `Settings` set `Geographic Target` to `United States`
- Get a .us domain
- Host your site in the US (not as important as the first two)

[This blog post from Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/working-with-multi-regional-websites.html) is a good read for this topic

Comment: That's great thanks. Maybe I should have included those in my question but it's good to know that I'm thinking along the same lines as others.

Answer (score 0):

As well as what John Conde's put make sure you use US spelling variations. Search engines treat common variations like color/colour as the same, but humans notice the difference.

Comment: I would have thought when you set the target in webmaster tools that would override any hints it takes from spelling. I'll delete my question when you've read this.